# Can someone explain what each pin does on an LM3914 dot/bar graph chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit, wire

I got an LM3914 chip to control a ten segment bar graph, but I am confused on how to wire it. [The data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf) is not helping me with what pins do what and how to wire it.

I need to know how it works and please don't be hyper technical I am still new to electronics.

Comment: On page 2 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf) is a typical application shown. What exactly do you not understand? And what result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just need to know what each pin does because the diagram does not really explain it that well to me.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. On future posts, please be sure to include links to any datasheets you're referencing, as well as any schematics or pictures of what you're trying to accomplish. It's difficult to ascertain where you're struggling when all we see is a wall of text.

Comment: What exactly do you want to make? It will be easier to help you if you specify your exact requirements: otherwise we'll have to explain all the ins and outs, which will be too much.

Comment: @jardane  Do you understand the block diagram on p.8 of the datasheet?  If not, then what specifically is not clear to you?

Comment: Sorry if I have not been clear, I thought my question was rather clear. I don't understand what each pin referenced on the data sheet does. 

the pins i need more clarity on are v-, v+, RLO, SIG, RHI, REF OUT and REF ADJ.

I feel like people are giving me the "it's too simple to explain" answer a lot but i don't know how else to ask and learn.

Comment: [This website](http://tronixstuff.com/2013/09/14/tutorial-lm3914-dotbar-display-driver-ic/) has a good tutorial on this chip. Unfortunately, the question is too broad to be answered here (see [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): questions should be reasonably scoped).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally the pins of an IC fall into four types and are pretty self explanatory:

(1) Power (where you connect the power supply)

(2) Input (where external signal go in)

(3) Output (where signals come out)

(4) Control (where you set the IC to do something e.g. reset)

You sometimes come across a pin marked NC - this means Not Connected so you don't have to worry about it. Here's a typical LM3914 circuit.

[image]

The POWER PINS are 2 (0V) and 3 (+12V)

The INPUT PIN is 5 (variable voltage input)

The OUTPUT PINS are 1, 18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10 (10 **sink** outputs)

This just leaves the CONTROL PINS. (4,6,7,8,9)

**Pin 6** (Rhi) and **Pin 4** (Rlo) are connected to the HI and LO ends of an internal resistor network (10 x 1K0) which produces a reference voltage on each comparator input. In this circuit **pin 6** is connected to the +12V supply through R1 (100k variable) which controls the range of input voltage. To complete this comparator ladder **pin 4** is connected to ground.

**Pin 7** is an internal voltage reference out. (1.25V) Pin 8 is a reference voltage adjustment. By connecting **pin 8** to ground the output at pin 7 will be 1.25V. The load resistance put on **pin 7** will control the LED brightness - hence a 1K0 (R2) is connected to ground.

**Pin 9** controls the mode of display (bar or single LED) (see data sheet for full explanation page 9/10 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf)

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, if I want to test between 1 and 5 volts I connect at least five volts to pin 6 then ground pins 2 and 4 so my lower part of the range is zero. And if I ground 7 and 8 I will get 1.25 volts for the LEDs. If I put at least 0.5 volts through pin 5 the first light should light up, right?

Comment: @jardane Yes, pin 6 needs to be a stable reference voltage. Pin8 is connected to ground, **pin 7 needs to be connected through a resistor** as shown to control the brightness of the display.  You might want to look at http://www.sentex.ca/~mec1995/gadgets/batt3914.htm which shows a circuit for a 5V display. Note it uses the ref. voltage from pin7 to pin 6 and then reduces the input voltage (0-5V) through a voltage divider so it covers the same voltage range (0 - 1.25V).

Comment: Why does it need to be connected to ground through a resistor?

Comment: @jardane the current taken from this pin (7) is used by the chip to set the current (brightness) at the LED outputs. This means you don't have to have a separate resistor on each LED. This is a second control function - reference voltage AND brightness control. If you want to experiment with a brightness control connect a 620R and 5K variable in series between pin 7 and ground. Changing the resistance will change the brightness. Measure the voltage at pin 7 - it stays the same.

Comment: Hi Whats the purpose of typing pinmode(pin 9) to led#9 (pin 11) ?

The reason I ask, is that in dot mode, Im seeing this LED always illuminated, and its baffling me.
Normally I just tie dot mode to either vcc or ground.Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the circuit as drawn and yes you can tie it to V+ (pin3) which gives you a bar graph display, leave it open circuit which gives a dot display or if you have a larger display tie it to the first driver in the series (lowest voltage). I can see where this line could cause confusion so am editing the "and takes .." out. The data sheet gives a fuller explanation page9/10 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This chip is very straight forward and simple. It consists of 10 comparators and a reference voltage. As the input voltage varies, a proportional number of comparators (or just a certain one depending on mode) will drive a signal, generally an LED.

For the simplest application, say your supply was 5V and *pin Rlo* was GND and *pin ref adj* was GND. A resistor from *pin Ref out* to GND would set the current according to 12.5V/Radj = current per LED. This means that each LED does not need a current limiting resistor in series, the chip does this for you! A 600Ω resistor from *pin ref out* to GND would give you about 20mA/LED

Now you have a varying input signal. With a 5V supply each of the 10 comparator kicks on sequentially in 0.5V increments with the first at 0.5V and the 10th and 5.0V. If your input was 0-0.49V no LEDs would light. If your input was 2.0-2.49V then 4 LEDs would be on, etc.

If you want just the 4th LED on when the input is 2.0-2.49V instead of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th then you can use *pin mode* to set this up. Tying this pin to 100mV or less ensures "dot-mode" where only 1 LED is on at a time. Tying it above 100mV puts it in "bar mode" which is all LEDs up to bias point are on.

You can do fancier things with this IC such as chaining multiple units together or selecting a range of voltages that the input signal should be between but that requires actually reading the datasheet and putting a voltage divider between the *pin ref out* and *pin ref adj*. I only explained the simplest application of the IC as you didn't state your application goal.

**Edit summary of pins user was explicitly confused by:**

*Rlo* and *Ref out* set the range of the input signal. *Rlo* is the low side, and *Ref out* is the high side. If *Ref out* was 12.0V and *Rlo* was 0.0V then the LEDs would light proportionally to an input signal *SIG* between those values. 0 LEDs on until *SIG* is greater than 1.2V (since there are 10 comparators) and every 1.2V increase in *SIG* would drive another LED on.

*V+* as explained before is the positive terminal of your power supply to the IC. It also supplies the current to the LEDs. *V-* is the negative terminal of your power supply.

*Ref adj* is tricky. It can be used in conjunction with *Ref out* to not only set the current in each LED but to set a voltage reference which can be used to tune the range of input signal *SIG* you want. Say your supply was 24V but you wanted the LEDs to change to a signal corresponding from to 0-5V (instead of 24V). You would tie *V+* to 24V and then use a voltage divider like on pg 9 of the datasheet to set the Vout node to 5V (they give you the equation!). Resistors must be chosen to set the Vout node to the proper voltage **and** also scaled to get the current limit you desire.